# Android Background image in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

Hi I am doing up a basic android app and want to set the background in a class as an image.I don't want to do it in the XMl file as this class doesnt have an XML file its referenced from another file. Can anyone shed any light on this.

Thanks
steve

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear. Is your class a View ? If so you can use setBackgroundResource() :

```
yourView.setBackgroundResource(R.id.your_image);
```